# Need help on deploying node js project?

Tags: node.js

I am very much new to Node JS. I have developed a node js project, in my local machine I am running the command 'node app.js' through command prompt. Now I want to deploy this project in our QA environment. Can someone help me on how I can bundle project and deploy it in QA regions?

Also I need to set up an the environment specific variables out side the project so that other projects can use it. Please help me on this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy make a copy, then zip the copied directory and clone your application to you QA environment. In your QA environment, run:

```
npm install
```

Optionally, if you have any tests, you can run :

```
npm install
```

Also don't forget to set the environment:

```
NODE_EN=development
```

Comment: Thanks Geeth for quick reply. I have zipped the project and ran the command 'npm install APILogging.zip'. Then I got below errors.                        15 error not a package C:\Naveen\APILogging.zip
16 error addLocal Could not install C:\Naveen\APILogging.zip
25 error errno -4058
26 error enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\chappana\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3444-e0101430\unpack-d0e27b46757a\package.json'
26 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
26 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
27 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Comment: Do I need to unzip the file in QA environment and run the 'npm install' command from the directory where package.json exists?

Comment: yes, you need to unzip the package and in your command line or bash go into the unzipped directory and then run "npm install"